# maximum message width in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

In my Mozilla Thunderbird plain text messages are displayed by default with long lines wrapped to the window width. Is there a way to configure it to display plain text messages reflowed to something narrower, with a blank margin?

Answer (score 5):

- Go to `Tools > Options > Advanced > General` and open the `Config Editor...`
- After accepting the warning type `mailnews.wraplength` into the search (or simply `wrap` and find this setting)
- Default is "72"
- Set to "0" to disable wrapping or (say) "90" to use a longer wrap

This affects how messages are composed (if using plaintext) but does not affect HTML messages.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird has a add-on call [Columner](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/columner/?src=search) that may do what you need. If not, there may be another which you can look for at its add-on/extension [search page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/).